# Passing JavaScript variable into snippet

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I'm working on a search form for my ModX application that is consisted of a chunk and a snippet. What I'm trying to achieve is to pass what was entered into the search box into a javascript variable and then pass it to my snippet, however, the snippet receives the literal text, and not the value that I enter into the parameter when I call it.

I don't know if what I'm attempting is possible in ModX or if I need to take a different approach, but I would be hugely thankful for anyone who can provide any insight.

**Chunk:**

```
<script>
$('.search-btn').click(function() {
    var search = $('.search-entry').val();
    [[showSearchResults? &q=`search`]]
});
</script>
```

**Snippet:**

```
<?php
$search = $modx->getOption('q', $scriptProperties);
echo $search; // this always prints "search"
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this code makes sense:

```
<script>
    $('.search-btn').click(function() {
    var search = $('.search-entry').val();
    [[showSearchResults? &q=`search`]]
    });
</script>
```

The snippet call returns the result of snippet's execution with param **q** always equal to the string 'search' in your case and finally on your page you will have something like this:

```
<script>
    $('.search-btn').click(function() {
    var search = $('.search-entry').val();
    'search' // assuming your snippet just returns what has been passed to it.
    });
</script>
```

In order to accomplish your task you can use a simple trick. Call your snippet like this:

```
[[!yourSnippet? &yourVar=`[[!#POST.yourVar]]` ]] // or GET
```

Lets say this snippet call is located on a page accessible via url /test/ on your server. So, now you just have to send the parameters you collected from your search form using AJAX to the /test/ page where your snippet is:

```
var yourVar = $('.search-entry').val();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/test/",
   data: {yourVar: yourVar},
   success: success,
   dataType: "html"
});
```

Hope it helps :)

PS If you want to search Resource content and TV content, I can highly recommend an extra called [SimpleSearch](https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/simplesearch).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @curveball. I'm curious, is [[!#POST]] meant to pick up POST variables? If I wanted to, could I do the same with [[!#GET]]?

Comment: yes, it is meant to get post/get variables and transfer them to your actual script/snippet. Sure, it should work with GET as well. You can check it like adding url-parameter to an url where your snippet with [[!#GET.yourVar]] is located.

Comment: Note that you need FastField or pdoTools installed to use the `[[!#POST]]` or `[[!#GET]]` tags - those are not shipped in the core.